# How to get combined feeds for Artist and Fan Tweets in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, twitter

I need the artist tweets and fan tweets to be combined.

How to get combined feeds for Artist and Fan Tweets in iPhone?

Fan Tweets Link :

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=<artistname>
```

Artist Tweets Link:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=<TwitterNameForArtist>&count=50&page=1
```

Comment: Parse them and combine them in a NSDictionary or whatever you prefer.

Comment: @David Schiefer: I tried that but It doesnt combine the feeds as valueForKey in the dictionaries differ.

Comment: @David Schiefer: Hey I got it. Can you please post your abive question as an answer. So that I can accept and upvote it. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse them and combine them in a NSDictionary or whatever you prefer.